# Pass values from html form to JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an index.html page which lets the user enter values of their wifi hotspot name, password and security type.
You can see the form in the image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdfnT.png

What I wanted was to pass the password, name and security type to a JavaScript file app.js which looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN1g5.png

I want to pass the form values to be updated in the JavaScript where the lock.set function takes values. As you can see, I tried creating variables but failed.
I want to change the wifi name, password string in double quotes in the JavaScript file.
Is it possible?

Comment: Please post actual code, not images

Comment: You really should start with basic JavaScript tutorials, they would teach you this kind of things.

Comment: Just use a `<script>` tag with a `src` attribute set to the location of the script. Make sure that the tag is _after_ the elements in the DOM. Also make sure that your inputs have the correct id's for the selectors to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a button into your HTML and trigger a JavaScript function on click.

Like that in your HTML:

```
<button id="trigger-btn" onclick="createLock"></button>
```

Or directly subscribe to `click` event in your JS:

```
const button = document.querySelector('#trigger-btn')
button.addEventListener('click', createLock)
```

Where `createLock` is a function defined in your JS.

```
function createLock() {
  const lock = // ... your code
  const switchon = document.querySelector('#security').value
  // ... your code
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use form and add the method onSubmit in javascript for capture the password:

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="password" name="password" type="text" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
const f = document.getElementById("form")
f.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  const password = document.getElementById("password")
  //set password
})
```

Comment: I wait your comment